# get the name of image when i upload it

Tags: php, html

When I upload image :

```
 <h3 id="txt_i2">Img</h3><input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg" name="picture" size="chars">
```

How to get the name of the uploaded img using php ? I don't mean "picture". For example if the img is called cow.jpg   the get that "cow"

Comment: try splitting the resulting file name by "." and just getting the values before the last item in the list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anton, you can use the code below to get the image or any file name without extension.

```
$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['picture']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Comment: first I think that it works but now it doesn't.

$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                        var_dump($filename);

it gives me string(0) "" .. I tried everything

Comment: you just need to echo $filename; I am 100% sure it will work. in your case you have to change the code like  $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['picture']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);

Comment: umm I tried , In fact I must put that name of pic in database , so
i've got this ....` $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['picture']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);   $insert['img']=$filename; `  ... and it's still doens't want to put it , (I'm using smarty)

Comment: have you tried to echo or dump $filename to make sure that you are getting exact file name?

Comment: yea, and I told you than it gives me string(0) "" ,  where I can give you the whole code to see it

Comment: Anton, show me your html and php code here or any other question so that I can give your the exact code.

Comment: ** <h3 id="txt_i2">Снимка2:</h3><input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg" name="picture" size="chars">
 <input type="submit" class="classname" value="Запиши" name="submit">
**
             if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                 
                     
                         $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']. PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                        var_dump( $filename);
                       $insert['img']=$filename;

                  }            
**

Comment: change <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg" name="picture" size="chars"> to <input type="picture" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg" name="file" size="chars"> if you don't want to change the name of this field than change $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']. PATHINFO_FILENAME); to $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['picture']['name']. PATHINFO_FILENAME);

Comment: in the database it write in the field img - "Array" this is written

Comment: now when I var_dump it it prints me "array(3) { ["dirname"]=> string(1) "." ["basename"]=> string(1) "8" ["filename"]=> string(1) "8" }"

Comment: Try this code<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3 id="txt_i2">Снимка2:</h3>
    <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg" name="picture" size="chars"> 
    <input type="submit" class="classname" value="Запиши" name="submit"> 
  </form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['picture']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
  var_dump($filename);
}

Answer (score 5):

[POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) :

> `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`
>
> The original name of the file on the client machine.

So using the above, if you want the actual file name `cow.jpg`, it is stored in

```
$_FILES['picture']['name'];
```

If you want the name of the file without the extension, you can extrapolate that from the filename provided with [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) by setting the `PATHINFO_FILENAME` flag, which would return `cow`. If the image is named `cow.moo.jpg` it will return `cow.moo`:

```
$picture_filename = pathinfo($_FILES['picture']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="file">Filename:</label>
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Uploade Script**

```
<?php
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
 ?>
```

This give you file name, file type and file size.

Answer (score 1):

check [pathinfo](http://php.net/pathinfo)  there are some examples, so you just need to use **pathinfo** on `$_FILES` variable

Comment: You need to make this and your other answer comments

Answer (score 1):

In html, you should add a property to form element: enctype="multipart/form-data".

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = explode(".", $_FILES['picture']['name']); //split by '.'
array_pop($filename); //remove the last segment
$filename = implode(".", $filename); //concat it by '.'
```