# Adding Metadata to Html5 file upload

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to add metadata information along with html 5 images before they are uploaded?

**clarification**: html 5 images upload (like the drag and drop thumbnail method or single input file) [sample HTML 5 Upload/drag_drop](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/)

So say user is uploading 10 images, he will fill some text info for each image describing it, then this information will be saved on the server.
So for **each** thumbnail user can add "title","location","description" in text boxes.

the example below allows an upload of a single image and preview of a thumbnail, what I am trying to achieve is to interact with this thumbnail and submit some text to the server along with it.

**clarification 2**: this question is not related to the picture EXIF,
I am asking about general metadata information user can add to the picture, like "I took the picture right before my wedding", or "this picture of my old home" or like tags "Red"

```js
document.getElementById("files").onchange = function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
        document.getElementById("image").src = e.target.result;
    };

    // read the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" />
<img  width="100" height="140" id="image" />
```

Comment: Just put all you want in FormData object.

Comment: can I use FormData for each individual image? can you give example? I will accept

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure why you are getting down votes for this question. It may have something to do with your wording. I assume you mean Exif data rather then metadata. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif

For modifying Exif data of an image in JavaScript you can use [piexifjs](https://github.com/hMatoba/piexifjs) by hMatoba, it will allow you to modify the images Exif metadata before uploading to the server.

Hope this helps )

Comment: To answer on "why the downvotes", I feel the question is simply too vague. I haven't even considered the question is related to EXIF before I read your answer - not saying it isn't, just the fact this bit is completely unclear makes it a bad question.

Comment: no i don't mean Exif, I am uploading images, with each image i would like to upload textual description (the user will enter for each img), how to do that?

Comment: That _is_ Exif, isnt' it?

Comment: @DanielShillcock that's the way I understood the question )

Comment: no, Exif is not user manal data, its metadata from the camera, i am talking about user data when uploading, user wants to add description to the image, or tag them.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you need.
As charlietfl already said in the comments you can use `FormData`
Here is an example:

[First try with multiple inputs](https://jsfiddle.net/wvgad91r/)

Here you can see how it is saved than:

```
   {
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {
    "input1": "yourimg1", 
    "input2": "yourimg2"
  }, 
  "form": {
    "input1": [
      "house", 
      "london"
    ], 
    "input2": [
      "bridge", 
      "berlin"
    ]
  }, 
  "headers": {
    ....
}
```

Now you have your files and descriptions connected with the name of the input field. It is important that all the beloning inputfields have the same name.

So the file from `input1` belongs to the description in the array named `input1` and the file from `input2` to the array `input2` and so on.

A few good explanations you can find [**here**](https://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/forms/html5forms/) and if you want you can use [**this**](http://www.javascripture.com/FormData) site to test the code and output.

You can take the code from here. Add at the end of the js function

```
console.log(request.response);
```

and change the url to `http://httpbin.org/post`.

Or just play a little bit around with it.

**EDIT:**

If you want it with multiple files you can do it like this:

```js
var testForm = document.getElementById('test-form');
var div = document.getElementById('output');
var data;
  testForm.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'http://your.url/post', /* async = */ false);

    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('test-form'));

    request.send(formData);
  }
  
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = 
          [
            '<img src="', 
            e.target.result,
            '" title="',
            escape(theFile.name), 
            '"/><div class="desc"><div>Location:<input name="',
            escape(theFile.name),
            '"> </div><br><div>Title:<input name="',
            escape(theFile.name),
            '"></div><br><div>Description:<input name="',
            escape(theFile.name),
            '"></div><br></div>'
          ].join('');
          
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }
  
//makes description visible     
$(document).on("click","img",function(){
        $(this).next().css("display", "block");
    });


  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
.desc{
  display:none;
}
img{
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='test-form'>
  <input type="file" id="files" name='input1' multiple/><br>
  <output id="list"></output><br>
  <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Then this is you output:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {
    "input1": "all_your_images"
  }, 
  "form": {
    "favicon.png": [
      "1a", 
      "1b", 
      "1c"
    ], 
    "loginBackground.jpg": [
      "2a", 
      "2b", 
      "2c"
    ]
  }, 
  "headers": {
   ....}
```

The disadvantage is that all images are uploaded together.
As you can see now each description is safed in an array with the name of its beloning image.

```
<div>Location:<input name="', escape(theFile.name),'"> </div>
```

This gives the inputname the name of the belonging image.

So if you want to safe the images and descriptions on your server in an array or something like that you have to get the names of the uploaded images with PHP.

```
$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['picture']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

(see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510641/get-the-name-of-image-when-i-upload-it))

I know you want it with drag and drop, but the code would be to long with that.
If you still want to do this I can recomment you [this site](https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/).
You only have to add the functionality to my posted code and it should work.

If you want to safe the informations directly in the image then I only can point to the [answer of tnt-rox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41441755/5859685). Then you should visit his links and read more about exif.

Comment: thank you for that, see my code snippet, solution needed with a single file upload or html 5 drag&drop not multiple file input.

Comment: @user648026 ahh ok so all the imagefiles are uploaded at the same time and the user has three text boxes for each image? And than the user has to add the name of the image where the description belongs to? Or do he has to remember in which order he put the images in the fileupload and then has to enter the description in the same order? Or how do he know which imagedescription he's currently writing?

Comment: this HTML 5 drag and drop has thumbnails, when clicking on the thumbnail the UI should change to allow adding text

Comment: @user648026 see my edits, its not with drag and drop, but that should be not so difficult to implement with the link.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you put static image element. So I make a code that generates images and title text box for every file and this is the code snippet for what I reach

```js
var count = 0;
document.getElementById("files").onchange = function (e) {
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  
  image.width = "100";
  for(var i=0;i<this.files.length;i++){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      //Add the image
      var im = image.cloneNode();
      im.id= "image"+count;
      im.src = e.target.result;
      document.body.appendChild(im);
      //Add the title for example
      var title = document.createElement("input");
      title.id = "title-img"+count;
      title.placeholder= "Enter the title of image "+count;
      document.body.appendChild(title);
      count++;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
  }
};
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
        <input type="file" multiple id="files" />
 </body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For this Purpose, Just use the Form to get the details from the user. The code example is given below,

HTML Code,

```
<Form action="imageSave.php" method="Post">
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td> Title </td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="imageTitle" > </td> 
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Location</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="imageLocation" > </td> 
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Description</td>
    <td> <textarea name="description" > </textarea> </td> 
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Image </td>
    <td> <input type="file" name="files" > </td> 
  <tr>
 </table>
</Form>
```

In your Database add these Columns,

- TableName : tblImages
- Column 1 : id [int]
- Column 2 : imageTitle [varchar(255)]
- Column 3 : imageLocation [varchar(255)]
- Column 4 : description [text]
- Column 5 : imageName [varchar(255)]

Then use this PHP File (imageSave.php)

```
$imageTitle=$_POST['imageTitle'];
$imageLocation=$_POST['imageLocation'];
$description=$_POST['description'];
$imageName=$_FILES['files']['name'];

if ($_FILES["files"]["error"] == 0)
{
  $remove_these = array(' ','`','"','\'','\\','/','(',')');
  $newname = str_replace($remove_these,'',$_FILES['files']['name']);
  //Make the filename unique
  $newname = time().".".$extension;
  //Save the uploaded the file to another location
  $upload_path = "/images/$newname";
  //echo $upload_path;
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], $upload_path);

  // Query and Code to Update the Database
}
```

Comment: this solution will send the info per form not individual per thumbnail correct?

Comment: Yah, Mostly you can't attach the information with image

Comment: This does not answer the qestion asked.